# [__NSCFString superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, nsarray, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to copy a NSMutableArray* into NSArray*, but it does not works and it generates a **[__NSCFString superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** error . Here is the code:

```
//where gc is a NSDictionary*, recentKey is a NSString*, and _objects is a NSArray*
//gc is an singleton is used to save chache data, with NSKeyedUnarchiver class
//_objects is used to reload the UITableView's data

NSArray *savedNews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[gc objectForKey:recentkey]];

//this not works...why??
_objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:savedNews];
```

**Resolution:**

Yes, as Herman suggests, the error was external. The savedNews Array was using a class with NSEncoding with an error:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
//...where element was NSString* and not "UIImageView"
// element should be imgView
    if (imgView) [encoder encodeObject:element forKey:@"imgView"];
}
```

Thanks for all guys.

Comment: Which exactly line fails? Are you sure you posted all code in context?

Comment: _objects is a NSArray*. The line fails is the assignation of _objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your App is the superview of an NSString object fetched. 
I guess that you assigned an NSString object to something where a UIView is expected. 
Could be something like:

```
someButton.textLabel = someString; // wrong - but should generate a compiler warning
```

instead of

```
someButton.textLabel.text = someString; // correct
```

This is not directly related to your array issue.

Comment: As Hermann said, your problem is not related to the code you have provided. You have to double check the UI related code.

Comment: Only it happens if _objects is reassigned. Could it be posible that the fact of changing data affects to the UITableView or some of the views?

Comment: For a start you should determine exactly at what point of code execution the issue appears. Do not look for side effects like "It only happens when ...". Did you set an exception breakpoint? If not - do it. If you dont see an error message on the point of break then press the continue button one or two times more and you shold get closer to the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, check what the object in the dictionary is for that key.

```
NSLog(@"GC Object type for recentkey:%@", [[gc objectForKey:recentkey] class]);
```

You can only pass an NSArray to initWithArray:
So if that object isn't already an NSArray but you want that object to be IN an array. The do this..

```
id obj = [gc objectForKey:recentkey]; //Because I have no idea what this is
NSArray *savedNews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:obj];
```